# cosine similarity between documents (rows) - spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, cosine-similarity

I have spark job to compute the similarity between text documents:

```
RowMatrix rowMatrix = new RowMatrix(vectorsRDD.rdd());      
CoordinateMatrix  rowsimilarity=rowMatrix.columnSimilarities(0.5);
JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> entries = rowsimilarity.entries().toJavaRDD();

List<MatrixEntry> list = entries.collect();

for(MatrixEntry s : list) System.out.println(s);
```

the MatrixEntry(i, j, value) represents the similarity between columns(let's say the features of documents).But how can I  show the similarity between rows? 
suppose I have five documents Doc1,.... Doc5, We would like to show the similarity between all those documnts. 
How do we get that? 
any help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to transpose your matrix:
You should start from RowMaxtrix -> IndexedRowMatrix -> BlockMatrix -> transpose -> BlockMatrix -> IndexedRowMatrix -> RowMatrix

```
IndexedRowMatrix rowMatrix = new IndexedRowMatrix(vectorsRDD.rdd());
CoordinateMatrix  rowsimilarity= rowMatrix.toBlockMatrix().transpose().toIndexedRowMatrix().toRowMatrix().columnSimilarities(0.5);
JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> entries = rowsimilarity.entries().toJavaRDD();
List<MatrixEntry> list = entries.collect();
for(MatrixEntry s : list) System.out.println(s);
```